# Reduce map(map(map(list(string)))) terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Hi there is there any neat way to convert a map(map(map(list(string)))) into a map(map(list(string))) with terraform .

Here's what my input structure looks like :

```
   exception_expr_rule = {
   "project" = {
     "user" = {
       sqli-stable = [
         "value",
       ],
       xss-stable = [
         "value",
         "value",
         "value"
       ],
       rce-stable = [
         "value"
       ],
       ...... = []
     },
     "user2" = {
       xss-stable = [
         "value",
       ],
       other-subsubkey = [
         "value"
       ],
       other-subsubkey = [
         "value"
       ],
       other-subsubkey = [
         "value"
       ],
      }
      "userN" = {....}
   }}
```

and here's what i want it to look like :

```
exception_expr_rule = {
 "project.user" = {
    sqli-stable = [
      "value",
    ],
    xss-stable = [
      "value",
      "value",
      "value"
    ],
    rce-stable = [
      "value"
    ]
  },
"project.user2" = {
    xss-stable = [
      "value",
    ],
    other-subsubkey = [
       "value"
     ],
     .....
   }
"project.userN" = {.....}
}
```

Can you guys help me achieve this please ?

I tried via

```
    exception_expr_rule_list = flatten([
    for projects,value in var.expr_rule_list : [
      for user_name,exceptions in value: {
          key = "${projects}.${user_name}"
          value = exceptions
        }
    ]
  ])
```

But is not wat i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky but a combination of `flatten` and `for` loops gets you there.

I've tested this with Terraform v0.14.5 in the console.

First I defined a variable copying your input structure:

```
variable "exception_expr_rule" {
  type = map

  default = {
    "project" = {
      "user" = {
        sqli-stable = [
          "value"
        ],
        xss-stable = [
          "value",
          "value",
          "value"
        ],
        rce-stable = [
          "value"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I created a new `new` local variable which combines and flattens it:

```
locals {
  new = flatten([
    for key in keys(var.exception_expr_rule): [
      for subkey, subvalue in var.exception_expr_rule[key]: {
        "${key}.${subkey}" = subvalue
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

If I access it via `local.new[0]` I get the desired output:

```
> local.new[0]
{
  "project.user" = {
    "rce-stable" = [
      "value",
    ]
    "sqli-stable" = [
      "value",
    ]
    "xss-stable" = [
      "value",
      "value",
      "value",
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for support, but the problem is that my input structure is variable, i can have more subkeys and more users under the same project. Finally the result is per user base so i need to access via subekys can't work with a list unfortunatelly

Comment: Not sure what you mean, probably best if you extend your question to show an example. My solution works if you add more "projects" or "users" as the key is dynamically set via `"${key}.${subkey}"`, so project "foo" and user "bar" would produce `foo.bar`.

Comment: Updated my starting struct. Ok for the keys that are dinamically set, but on jour solution i can't do something like local.new["foo.bar"]["rce-stable"]

Comment: Because of the outer `flatten` the map is wrapped in a list with just one element so you need access it with `local.new[0]`, i.e. `local.new[0]["foo.bar"]["rce-stable"]` will get you there.

Comment: Solved doing 
 new = {for pair in flatten([
    for key in keys(var.exception_expr_rule_list): [
      for subkey, subvalue in var.exception_expr_rule_list[key]: {
        key = "${key}.${subkey}"
        value = subvalue
      }
    ]
  ]): "${pair.key}" => pair.value }

Answer (score 2):

Solved doing

```
    new = {for pair in flatten([ 
       for key in keys(var.exception_expr_rule_list): [ 
          for subkey, subvalue in var.exception_expr_rule_list[key]: { 
              key = "${key}.${subkey}" 
              value = subvalue 
          } 
        ] 
       ]): "${pair.key}" => pair.value 
}
```